# vba function for multiple statement

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

Hello I'm looking to create a vba functions from an excel function.
The excel function works correctly but problem is function is very long and maximum number of "if" is reached.

This is a part of the excel function:

```
=IF(E49>=E50+$A$1;1;IF(E49<=E50-$A$1;-1;IF(E48>=E50+$A$1;1;IF(E48<=E50-$A$1;-1;IF(E47>=E50+$A$1;1;IF(E47<=E50-$A$1;-1;IF(E46>=E50+$A$1;1;IF(E46<=E50-$A$1;-1;0)))))))
```

I need a simple if statement that tell if cell E49 is >= of E50+$A$1 or <= of cell E50-$A$1, if not move on upper cell E48 and check if value is >= of E50+$A$1 or <= of cell E50-$A$1, in not move on upper cell E47, otherwise return 0

I need to start an if loop that end when the statement is reached.
The example is a small part of excel code but it can be very long because if statement is not reached on cell close to E50, can finish to cell E3 or E1 creating a very long code. My need is to remove all this extra code by creating a loop.

I hope I've explained well.

e.g.

[excel image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49pCM.png)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "I hope I've explained well". I'm sorry, but I don't think that you have. Ending the description of a condition by `...` is not a good sign. It assumes we understand the pattern, which isn't a safe assumption to make about someone who is not immersed in the particulars of your problem in the same way that you are.

Comment: Another problem with your description, surely `E49 is >= or <= of cell E50+$A$1` is *always* true since given any two numbers `x` and `y`, either `x >= y` or `x <= y`.

Comment: IF(E49>=E50+$A$1;1;IF(E49<=E50-$A$1;-1; it's >= plus A1 or <= minus A1

Comment: It might be better to just explain what you are trying to do with column `E`. What are all of these `If` statements supposed to *do*? You have only (partially) explained what condition they are supposed to check. It is easy enough to write a VBA loop which loops over a range of cells, checking each cell for some condition, but nothing in what you have written clearly says what that loop is supposed to do beyond checking some conditions. Put a single value in a cell? Put 50 values in 50 cells? What values? Where are these values supposed to go?

Comment: To elaborate on @JohnColeman last comment: Sometimes with a complicated problem, it may be better to rethink how you are trying to solve the problem, rather than getting hung up on an implementation of a complex solution that might or might not be the best approach.

Comment: sorry John try to explain better, my english language is a problem and my programming knownledge too!! on column E there are casual numbers. My function is on cell F50 and check if: given the value of cell E50 (e.g. 55), looking to upper cells, check if in the upper range, starting from E49, check which conditions occour firstly, if bigger than E50+A1 or smaller than E50-A1. If A1=3. (e.g. check if in previous range there's a number bigger than 55+3, or smaller than 55-3). When the condition occurs give me +1 if value is bigger or -1 if value is smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, perhaps this:

**edit:** typo in sign in `condition` statement

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((E3:E49>=E50+$A$1)+(E3:E49<=E50-$A$1))=0,0,LOOKUP(2,1/((E3:E49>=E50+$A$1)-(E3:E49<=E50-$A$1))))
                                 ^
```

- Returns `0` if neither condition is met for `E3:E49`
- Returns `1` if the first condition met (starting from `E49` and working up) is the `>=`
- Returns `-1` if the first condition met is the `<=`

Comment: Wow Ron, this work perfectly for my needs. Thank you very much, I really appreciate your precious help!! but I understand I have really much to learn. :)

Comment: @muraglia The solution is a use of array formulas. Work through with the formula evaluation tool to get an idea of how it works.